# Error message from grm() in ltm: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, survey, psychometrics, item-response-theory

I am analyzing a survey data set. One of the items in the survey is:

```
"I plan to work hard in my statistics course"  
1=Strongly Disagree 
2=Disagree 
3=Neither Disagree or Agree 
4=Agree 
5=Strongly Agree
```

No one selected option 1 of Strongly Disagree.  This is to be expected but the function `grm()` in package `ltm` generates an error: `"Subscript out of bounds"`.

How do I get around this problem and still keeping the responses as they are or without removing that item?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

As the help page of `?grm` points out

> grm() can also handle binary items, which should be coded as ‘1, 2’
>   instead of ‘0, 1’.

This means that items have to include 1 as a value. So, therefore you have to recode the variable in such a way that it starts at 1. So the easiest thing would be to subtract 1 from each value for the variable in your example!

Comment: "subtract -1" would be the same as "add 1". Did you really mean that? It would seem to make more sense to subtract 1

Comment: You were right I changed it

Answer (score 1):

[This question might be better off on SO since it's mainly about how to do something in `R`.]

Here's an example that illustrates the problem and two possible solutions:

```
## Generate data and run grm()
dat <- data.frame(w=as.factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)), 
                    x=as.factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)),
                    y=as.factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)), 
                    z=as.factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)))
grm(dat)
# 
# Call:
# grm(data = dat)
#
# Coefficients:
#    Extrmt1  Extrmt2  Extrmt3   Extrmt4  Dscrmn
# w   -0.802   -0.162    0.388     0.802   4.136
# x  611.563  279.736  -84.675  -441.193  -0.002
# y   -5.898   -3.247    0.150     3.287   0.328
# z   15.681    3.388   -6.762   -18.028  -0.106
#
# Log.Lik: -631.277
```

So that works. Now, remove the "1" value, rerun the model and see what happens:

```
with(dat, table(x))
# x
#  1  2  3  4  5 
# 19 15 21 19 26 
# dat$x[dat$x == "1"] <- "2"
grm(dat)
# Error in log.pr[xj, ] : subscript out of bounds 
## Here's your problem:
with(dat, table(x))
# x
#  1  2  3  4  5 
#  0 34 21 19 26
```

So one solution as Huub Hoofs suggested is to subtract 1 from the variable(s) that have counts of 0:

```
dat <- within(dat, x <- as.numeric(x))
dat <- within(dat, x <- (x - 1))
with(dat, table(x))
# x
#  1  2  3  4 
# 34 21 19 26 
grm(dat)
# grm(dat)
# 
# Call:
#   grm(data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
# w
# Extrmt1  Extrmt2  Extrmt3  Extrmt4   Dscrmn  
# -0.805   -0.163    0.390    0.806    4.039  
# 
# x
# Extrmt1  Extrmt2  Extrmt3   Dscrmn  
# -99.579   30.061  156.913    0.007  
# 
# y
# Extrmt1  Extrmt2  Extrmt3  Extrmt4   Dscrmn  
# -5.876   -3.236    0.149    3.273    0.330  
# 
# z
# Extrmt1  Extrmt2  Extrmt3  Extrmt4   Dscrmn  
# 15.575    3.366   -6.715  -17.903   -0.106  
# 
# 
# Log.Lik: -607.946
```

You could also use `droplevels()`:

```
dat <- within(dat, x <- droplevels(x))
```

Comment: That will work unless you actually need those levels. What if you are doing subgroup or DIF analysis and one group has 0s in a level and the other doesn't?